# Chimp timing out while running in docker container

Tags: node.js, meteor, chimp.js

I am getting the error within a docker container using xvfb and chrome:

`node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/cucumberjs/hooks.js:19 function timed out after 60000 milliseconds`

full log: http://pastebin.com/7yHq28dT

It runs fine locally, but i can't seem to get it to run in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Webdriver can't connect to selenium to get a session locally. Chimp dynamically sets a port and starts selenium with it. So you can see the server in your logs started on

http://localhost:44858/wd/hub

You should pass Chimp a port using `--port`, perhaps use something the usual Selenium 4444 port, and then make sure your docker container allows local connections to 4444.